# No Data connection on emulator using Windows Device center 6 on win8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-8, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, wmdc

I am developing WinMobile 6 application using Visual Studio 8 on Windows 8.

When i cradle the emulator i dont get data on the emulator. As you can see from the image i have data connection checked in connection settings. 
[image]

Win7 used to show a phone image in Device center when i cradle an emulator; but Win8 shows a laptop image(i'm using laptop) - i dont know if this is some sign something is wrong.

Except for not having data on the emulator everything seems to work fine. When i deploy my program it gets to the device fine.

I tried cradling and un-cradling different emulators to get this to work per similar SO post but that did not help.

What could be wrong here? thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done exercise 4 from MSDN without any luck. [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb278114.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As you can deploy and debug apps from VS using the established connection, the connection is working in general. WMDC always sets up a TCP/IP connection, a normal (PPP) or enhanced (RNDIS) one.

In WMDC-Mobile Device Settings is a connection setup where you can switch the PASSTHRU options:

This computer is connected to:

- Automatic
- Work Network
- The Internet

[image]

Often I have to switch between "Automatic" and "Internet" to get a working internet connection on the dvice thru the WMDC connection.

Now you should be able to open a web page on the device. If not, possibly a firewall setting blocks the connection. You possibly want to follow http://modernnomads.info/wiki/index.php?page=Windows+Mobile+Device+Center+Troubleshooting to troubleshoot further.

The "Allow data connections on device..." option enables the device to use another WLAN or WWAN connection and should always be ticked.